# Excluding others from Kaddish on Yahrtzeit

Tags: tefilla, mourning-aveilus, yahrtzeit

There seems to be a minhag in some of the shuls in the large Jewish community I live in which features the gabbai yelling "Yahrtzeit" near the end of davening. At that point, only the individual with a yahrtzeit says kaddish. What is this minhag based on? Why do we exclude the other mourners from saying kaddish at that point?

Comment: I think you have it backwards: why do we allow other mourners to say kaddish along at other points? They have months of Kaddish and he just has today.

Comment: Also note that such shuls will usually say something that will allow other people to say kaddish after aleinu.

Comment: @DoubleAA has a very strong point. In a historical context kaddish was said by _one_ person, not a group, and that person would be the one with the highest "priority".